# How to expand function arguments in Vim command line?

Tags: vim

Vim's [Utl](https://github.com/vim-scripts/utl.vim) plugin offers a convenient way for doing web queries from within the editor. When called directly from the command line, a dictionary lookup can be done like this:

```
:Utl ol http://dict.leo.org/?search=my+search+term
```

What's the correct way for defining a custom command with the same purpose (`my+search+term` being user input)? I can't seem to get `<f-args>` right with this one:

```
command -nargs=1 SearchLeo :exe ":Utl ol http://dict.leo.org/?search=" . expand("<f-args>")
```

What's the correct way of defining function arguments here? Or should I turn this into a more complete function? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You probably don't need `expand()` here; it's just for expanding globs (like `*.txt`) or the special variables like `%` for the current file.
2. You're quoting the argument twice, once through `<f-args>` (`<q-args>` would be slightly more correct, though it only matters with a variable number of arguments), once literally.

Use this:

```
command -nargs=1 SearchLeo :exe ":Utl ol http://dict.leo.org/?search=" . <q-args>
```

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks very much, also for the explanation!